# How to do logging in matlab : anything similar to logging like python

Tags: python, matlab, logging

I am new to matlab:

I was working in python, I generally use logging a lot to keep track of the code. In python, we can use below

```
import logging
logger = logging.getlogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.FileHandler("log.txt",mode=w+)
handler.setlevel(loggin.INFO)
logger.addHandler(handler)

#And any where in the code use it as

logger.info("testing")
```

How can we do something similar in matlab

Comment: MATLAB has a wonderful debugger, you should look into that rather than logging. Plus, you can use `warning` to output comments for the user that can be turned off.

Comment: debugger is good, but if we have logging, its like you can just turn on and off and on a sepated file we can see what happened. good to track

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no built-in logging feature in Matlab. So you need to use third-party or undocumented tools.

Matlab ships the Java logging libraries [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) and [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) with its bundled JVM. You can make use of them for your logging. There's a Matlab [SLF4M library](https://github.com/janklab/SLF4M) that provides a layer of convenient Matlab bindings for SLF4J/log4j. (Full disclosure: I wrote SLF4M.)

There are also some native M-code Matlab logging libraries available on the MathWorks File Exchange:

- [Matlab Logging Facility](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42078-matlab-logging-facility?s_tid=srchtitle)
- [log4m](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37701-log4m-a-powerful-and-simple-logger-for-matlab?s_tid=srchtitle)
- [log4matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33532-log4matlab?s_tid=srchtitle)

Comment: https://github.com/janklab/SLF4M looks very much what i wanted. Can we use string concatenation like `logging.debug("a :: "+string(a)+" :: b :: "+string(b))` instead of `sprintf` format like `logging.debug("a :: %s :: b :: %s,(a,b))`

Comment: Yes. String concatenation works in any context where a plain string works. (And if SLF4M chokes on the fact that it's a `string` instead of a `char`, I'll put in a fix for it quickly.)